# Can I format a number before it is rendered in <Text>

Tags: dart, flutter

I am rendering a `<Text>` node in Flutter app something like:

```
We have total ${_summary['bookCount']} books.
```

`_summary` is retrieved via a remote API and `bookCount` is one of the returned JSON field. It normally is more than 1,000.

If I display the book count like that, it is a plain `1234`. I would like to make it be shown as `1,234`.

Currently, I have to manually modify that field using some formatter but this is cumbersome.

I am looking for something like:

```
We have total ${myNumberFormat(_summary['bookCount'])} books.
```

grammar, where *myNumberFormat* is a function.

In my previous programming in PHP and Twig, this can be done with a filter.

Much appreciate your input.

**Update**

@raju-bitter

This solution is what I know and is absolutely correct. What I am looking for is an inline "filter".

With this solution, a few things I don't like, the most of which is that, I have to split my one liner of text into several few segments:

`We have {XXX} books, accumulating to {YYY} pages, and {ZZZ} word counts.`

This sentence will be broken to 7 parts at least so that each number text section can be formatted via a `formatter` and then wrapped in a surrounding `<Text>`.

I am trying to see if there are more straightforward ways to do so.

Comment: You can define the formatter in a separate file with other common functions widely used throughout your app, and then use it like: `"We have ${common.format(XXX)} books, accumulating to ${common.format(YYY)} pages, and ${common.format(ZZZ)} word counts."`

Answer (score 70):

There is a Dart package for formatting numbers, the [Dart intl package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl). To use the package, add the following line to the Dart dependencies: `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

Here's what my dependencies look like with the line:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    intl: ^0.17.0
```

Click *packages get* in IntelliJ, or run `flutter packages get` from the command line.

Make sure your class imports the `intl` package:

`import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;`

In your code, you can use NumberFormat class to do the formatting:

```
  final formatter =  intl.NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(1234) // formatted number will be: 1,234
```

Full stateful widget example:

```
class NumberFormatExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NumberFormatExampleState createState() => new _NumberFormatExampleState();
}

class _NumberFormatExampleState extends State<NumberFormatExample> {
  final formatter = intl.NumberFormat.decimalPattern();
  int theValue = 1234;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text(formatter.format(theValue));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, How can I separate by dot? (.)

Comment: @PedroMassango First, convert the number to string then you can replace the ',' with a '.'

Comment: It was the first thing I've tried and didn't worked. I fixed it by creating a custom currency's country code

Comment: this only gets you stuck with a thousand currency. what happens if you go beyond like a million?

Answer (score 14):

An update for above answers:

First add `intl` package into your `pubspec.yaml` file, just after `flutter sdk` (like below):

```
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      intl: ^0.16.0
```

If you use `flutter_localizations`, `intl` must be above of that.

Now you can use `NumberFormat` class.

Some examples:

```
print(NumberFormat.currency().format(123456)); // USD123,456.00

print(NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'eu').format(123456)); // 123.456,00 EUR

print(NumberFormat.currency(name: 'EURO').format(123456)); // EURO123,456.00

print(NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'eu', symbol: '?').format(123456)); // 123.456,00 ?

print(NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'eu', decimalDigits: 3).format(123456)); // 123.456,000 EUR

print(NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'eu', customPattern: '\u00a4 #,##.#').format(123456)); // EUR 12.34.56,00
```

- Reference & More information: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-formatting-currency-with-numberformat#supported-locales
- NumberFormat Class Dart API: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html

Answer (score 4):

Using [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package,

```dart
double number = 1234;
String output = NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(number); // 1,234
```

Answer (score 3):

In for loop you can try:

```
Text('Index ${i}'), //Index 0
```

Format with operation:

```
Text('Total: \$${price * quantity}'),  //$20
```

With Decimal point:

```
Text('\$${cart.totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2)}'), //2.34
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Flutter package that allows you to format text input with predefined patterns.
First add the following line to the Dart dependencies: pubspec.yaml file:

````
    pattern_formatter: ^1.0.2```
then import it in your dart code
    import 'package:pattern_formatter/pattern_formatter.dart';

Example: Thousand group
    TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      inputFormatters: [
      ThousandsFormatter()
    ],
   )

Decimal Number
    TextField(
     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
     inputFormatters: [
     ThousandsFormatter(allowFraction: true)
  ],
 )

Card number grouping 

    TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      inputFormatters: [
      CreditCardFormatter(),
    ],
   )

Date format

    TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      inputFormatters: [
      DateInputFormatter(),
  ],
)
````

Answer (score 0):

Using the intl package will limit you to format numbers without decimals. You can make it easy with a function for counting positions and add the thousands separator where it's needed.

```
String numf(String n) {
  var numArr = n.split('');
  String revStr = "";
  int thousands = 0;
  for (var i = numArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (numArr[i].toString() == ".") {
      thousands = 0;
    } else {
      thousands++;
    }
    revStr = revStr + numArr[i].toString();
    if (thousands == 3 && i > 0) {
      thousands = 0;
      revStr = revStr + ',';
    }
  }
  return revStr.split('').reversed.join('');
}
```