# Flutter multiple decimal number incorrect

Tags: flutter

I'm newbie in Flutter and facing with calculator issue below:

```
num total = 22.9 * 3.0;
```

The result is `68.6999999999` instead `68.7`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help, using the number format https://stackoverflow.com/a/43636254/4712391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var total = 22.9 * 3.0;

print(total.toStringAsFixed(2));
```

Ans : 68.70

Reference link : https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html