# Flutter NumberFormat format without changing language

Tags: flutter, locale, currency, number-formatting

I am trying to format the number according to selected currency without translating it. For example the

```
Text(NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
    locale: 'bn_BN',
).format(123456.78));
```

outputs

```
১,২৩,৪৫৬.৭৮৳
```

I want the format but not on the locales language. How do i get it to look like this instead -

```
1,23,456.78 BDT or 1,23,456.78 ৳
```

Is there a way to achieve this

P.S. I just need the thousands seperator or grouping to be what the currency default is for example BDT grouping is  XX,XX,XXX  first comma after thousand then comma after each 2 digits. This is something the NumberFormat does on its own but unfortunately only when u pass in locale.

Comment: What should "123456789.78" look like when formatted?

Comment: i said that in the question 1,23,456.78 BDT  or 1,23,456.78 ৳

Comment: This is why I've asked about the number that is 1000x times bigger than in your example.

Comment: Thepeanut 12,34,56,789.78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom NumberFormatter somewhere in your code (assuming that you will use it in different parts of your application) and format() numbers using it:

```dart
final myFormatter = new NumberFormat.currency(
      name: 'BDT',
      decimalDigits: 2,
      customPattern: '#,##,##0.00 \u00A4',
    );
```

```dart
Text(myFormatter.format(12345678.01)),
```

This will result in: 1,23,45,678.01 BDT

Comment: Thank you for pointing the right direciton. I ended up making a global function that fetches the pattern and symbol from locale and then format with just those 2 things .

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer in another question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61530490/6704033

The last example is the one you want to use with your format `#,##,##0.00`

I don't think you want to provide your BN locale because that's whats causing the localised numbers. Maybe leave this default or set to 'en'.

```dart
var myNumberFormat = NumberFormat('#,##,##0.00', 'en');
var myString = '${myNumberFormat.format(123456.78} ৳';
```